# Are others experiencing problems with PayPal

Tags: paypal

We're recently having problems with PayPal payments leaving transactions in a Pending state even though the PayPal payment goes thru.

Comment: In order for people to give you a better answer you should complete the question with information such as the CMS you are using (Drupal, WordPres,..), its version, as well as the CiviCRM version.

Answer (score 1):

What version of CiviCRM do you use? In at least two of the latest versions released recently there is some Paypal bugs that has been fixed. You should first of all make sure you have the latest version installed.

You can see it in release notes for:

- [5.31.1](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/release-notes/5.31.1.md)
- [5.32.0](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/release-notes/5.32.0.md)